# Ruby update by keeping the current redmine installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I have redmine 3.3.2 installed. I connect it to my current db and copied files folder to it(I already have a redmine 1.3.x version running in one server). My ruby version is 'ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x64-mingw32]' and I am using windows. I have added some new plugins too and everything is working fine. When I try to add a particular plugin,it throws an error since the plugin requires ruby version > 2.1. What are the procedures I should follow so that I can update ruby and continue to use he current redmine with all my data and plugins?

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading from 1.3.x to 3.3.2, chances that your plugins will simply work after upgrading are very slim, due to different version of Rails, and also changes in Redmine's API.

I would recommend that you first uninstall plugins on 1.3.x, then follow official upgrade instructions, from Redmine's website:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade

which would update Redmine's database and files properly, without errors. And then you should search for updated version of each plugin that you used on 1.3.x separately, compatible with Redmine 3, and install those plugins again.

Answer (score 0):

You can update Ruby to the current version using Ruby version manager (RVM). See this link on how to update Ruby using RVM. https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading.

The following command should update your Ruby installation to the latest version:

**`curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`**